how to override plan without trial when revising the subscription to new plan on PayPal?
We can upgrade or downgrade a subscription by changing the plan within the same Product using the /v1/billing/subscriptions/{id}/revise endpoint. We have to provide the new Plan ID in the Post body for our existing subscription within the Product.
I have two plans in my current application Basic and Professional. This is what their billing cycles look like after creation.
// Billing Cycle for Basic
[
  {
    frequency: {
      interval_unit: 'DAY',
      interval_count: 7,
    },
    sequence: 1,
    tenure_type: 'TRIAL',
    pricing_scheme: {
      fixed_price: {
        value: '0',
        currency_code: 'USD',
      },
    },
    total_cycles: 1,
  },
  {
    frequency: {
      interval_unit: 'MONTH',
      interval_count: 1,
    },
    sequence: 2,
    tenure_type: 'REGULAR',
    pricing_scheme: {
      fixed_price: {
        value: '10',
        currency_code: 'USD',
      },
    },
    total_cycles: 0, // 0 means infinite
  },
];

// Billing Cycle for Premium
[
  {
    frequency: {
      interval_unit: 'DAY',
      interval_count: 7,
    },
    sequence: 1,
    tenure_type: 'TRIAL',
    pricing_scheme: {
      fixed_price: {
        value: '0',
        currency_code: 'USD',
      },
    },
    total_cycles: 1,
  },
  {
    frequency: {
      interval_unit: 'MONTH',
      interval_count: 1,
    },
    sequence: 2,
    tenure_type: 'REGULAR',
    pricing_scheme: {
      fixed_price: {
        value: '20',
        currency_code: 'USD',
      },
    },
    total_cycles: 0, // 0 means infinite
  },
];

What I want
What I want is that once the user buys a Basic Plan let's say and after 3 days he wants to upgrade it to Premium then I don't want to start as a free trial in the premium plan but as a Regular billing cycle, which means I want to skip the trial part when a user upgrades his/her subscription.
What I have researched
I have found that in the revise-endpoint you can also send one plan object to customize the subscription, see here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_revise

So when making a request I was passing plan like this:
// making request using Paypal SDK, I know it's deprecated but I will change that later
  request.requestBody({
    plan_id: priceId,
    application_context: {
     ....// info here
    },
    plan: {
      billing_cycles: [
        {
          sequence: 1,
          total_cycles: 0,  // I was thinking it would remove trial, I know for regular one this is interpreted as infinity
        },
        {
          sequence: 2,
          total_cycles: 0,
          frequency: {  
            interval_unit: "DAY",  
            interval_count: 1  
          }
        }
      ]  
    },  
  });

//But I got this error from the PayPal
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","issue":"INVALID_TRIAL_BILLING_TOTAL_CYCLES",
"description":"Total cycles for trial billing must be greater than '0'."}]....]}


// other attempt I made is to start from sequence 2 directly but this doesn't work
// I didn't got the error using below but it I think included trial from existing
// price_id I am passing as a plan_id
  request.requestBody({
    plan_id: priceId,
    application_context: {
     ....// info here
    },
    plan: {
      billing_cycles: [
        {
          sequence: 2,
          total_cycles: 0,
          frequency: {  
            interval_unit: "DAY",  
            interval_count: 1  
          }
        }
      ]  
    },  
  });

I have also read this community forum: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/subscription-create-override-plan-frequency-interval/td-p/3033004
Looks like I have to create a different plan but still want to know if anyone came across this kind of problem in their application.
References

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/revise-subscriptions
How can i change plan for subscription in paypal api
Have one Plan that can create customer subscription with free trial or without free trial

